# Cannot assign to read only property 'props' of #<Object> error when trying to change React state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-state, rtk-query

Here is my code :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useCountriesQuery } from '../store/apis/userApi';

const  CountryCmp = () => {

  const {data} = useCountriesQuery('FR')

  const [countryArray, setCountryArray] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if(data){
      setCountryArray(data.countries) // data.countries = [ { "selected": false, "value": "Afghanistan" }, { "selected": false, "value": "Afrique du Sud" }... { "selected": false, "value": "Allemagne" }, { "selected": True, "value": "France" }]
    }
  }, [data])
  
  const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState('France')
  
  const updateSelectedCountry = (value) => {
    setSelectedCountry(value)
    let clonedCountryArray = [...countryArray]

    clonedCountryArray.map(item => {
      if(item.selected === true){
        item.selected =  false
      }
      return item
    })
    clonedCountryArray.map(item => {
      if(item.value === value){
        item.selected =  true   
         
      }
      return item 
    })
    console.log('countries', clonedCountryArray)
    setCountryArray(clonedCountryArray)
  }
  
  
 return <>
          {countryArray && <div className="pp-cons" >
            <div className="col_form_full" >
              <div>
                <span data-ppui="true">{selectedCountry}</span>
                <div>
                  <ul >
                      {countryArray.map((item,id) => {
                        return <li onClick={() => updateSelectedCountry(item.value)} key={id} >
                                  <p >
                                      <span className={"pp-"+(item.selected ? '_strong' : '')} > {item.value} </span>
                                    
                                  </p>
                              </li>})}
                  </ul>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>}
        </> 
}

export default CountryCmp;
```

Here data are fetched correctly from REST API through RTK Query (useCountriesQuery).

When I click to invoke updateSelectedCountry, I got this error :

```
Cannot assign to read only property 'selected' of object '#<Object>'
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'selected' of object '#<Object>'
```

I thought countryArray was the problem, so I cloned it to not avail.

I don't understand why. Please help!

Comment: You are copying top level (array) but objects within may still be references to the data downloaded, I dont think you can modify underlying data that way, what are you trying to achieve? Maybe you need to make a copy at the time of fetch (e.g. using query and dispatch action with an editable copy (to other redux slice).